# When clicking on User Profile, please have Mod Dashboard selected as default for Moderators

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, moderator-tools, moderator-abilities

Majority of the times, I'm likely to click on a user profile because the user's a spam user, or to check if the user's sock.

Can we please have the Mod dashboard selected as default for Moderators?

Comment: Wasn't a survey supposed to come out to us diamonds about the mod dashboard? And wasn't this very request supposed to be part of that survey? Two weeks ago that survey was supposed to come out "shortly" and "soon". I guess these are new synonyms for "6-8 weeks".

Comment: yeah, seems like the survey is due to be out soon, didn't realize that - not as regular in chat now. Thanks for letting me know, will keep the question on though.

Comment: Totally agree. If I'm going to a user profile as a mod it's not because I want to see how many people they've reached.... if this isn't implemented then hopefully at least the Account Info box can be shown be default.

Comment: @ArthurFischer The survey link should be included in the mod newsletter when it comes out (and this question is indeed in said survey). I'll check where the newsletter is at.