# When a moderator clicks on a user's profile, don't automatically go the Activity tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, moderator-tools

When you click on your own profile, it automatically goes to the Activity tab. When you click on a user as a non-mod, it goes to the 'Profile' tab.

As a mod... it goes to the 'Activity' tab when you click on another user's profile. This is *annoying*, because often I want to see the *profile*, and *then* maybe head over to the Activity tab.

Can we please either have the option to choose which we want as our default, or just keep it the same as normal users?

Comment: I vote for choice.

Comment: No mention of the mod dashboard? That's the tab I usually want to go to.

Comment: @ifajra - that's already [a different feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263946/when-clicking-on-user-profile-please-have-mod-dashboard-selected-as-default-for).

Comment: This decision was made because the Activity tab has more useful information for a moderator and particularly to staff, and a lot of others get irritated having to click on the Activity tab *every single time* because the Profile tab simply is not useful to them. Then we started building the Mod Dashboard as an *even more* convenient place for moderators to go to but it never quite got the finishing touches.

Comment: Before this change I hated having to click from the not-useful-to-me profile to activity *every single time*.  If as a mod I'm looking at a user, it's probably because I want to know what he's been up to lately.  I don't care about his all-time greatest hits or his "about me" text at that point.

Comment: @animuson It's more useful *except* that it's missing the “last seen” info, which I very often want to see when I click a user. (Why “last seen” activity isn't in the Activity tab, I will never understand!) So yes, I'm voting for this because landing on a different page as a mod than as a regular user is disorienting, especially because it lacks that crucial bit of information that's on the “landing page” I'm used to seeing when I click a username.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Have you tried clicking on the "Account Info" link at the top instead? (It's off to the right next to the Mod link.) That opens a small yellow box with additional information. I never think about it because that box opens by default for staff. Easy to user-script it to always be open, though.

Comment: @animuson That never really occurred to me since I already know where to find that info normally. Granted, now that's been pointed out it's still a second click, but at least it loads faster. (However, I kinda *don't* want that banner automatically open all the time, even if I could write a userscript easily for it — when the site automatically opens it for a mod, it's because it contains something unusual that probably needs my attention. The “open” state for that is already meaningful, so I don't want to clobber that.)

Answer (score 4):

Dissenting view here - The activity tab has much more *useful* information than the profile page. Its less busy than the mod dashboard (sorry guys!) but isn't mostly fluff. Top tags and questions can be interesting, but I'd much rather get to the tasty stuff like votes and reputation counts

Also looks like the default behaviour for clicking on your own account so, making it consistent and going to activity first no matter what makes sense.

Comment: Fwiw, an option to choose the default would alleviate the primary concern here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, quick and dirty, but, [here](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/DefaultProfileTab.user.js)...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sloppy default to profile view
// @namespace    https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230261/jason-c
// @version      1.0
// @description  Switch user profile view to profile tab
// @author       Jason C
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/users/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/users/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/users/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/users/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/users/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/users/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    if (/\/users\/[0-9]+\/.*/.test(window.location) && !window.location.href.includes("tab=")) {
        if (window.location.href.includes("?"))
            window.location = window.location + "&tab=profile";
        else
            window.location = window.location + "?tab=profile";
    }

})();
```

Could be improved by testing the profile tab for the `youarehere` class, or something similar, to avoid an unneeded reload when you're a normal user.

Change `tab=profile` in the script to whatever you want if you'd prefer a different tab.

An alternate strategy that would prevent page reloads, if somebody wanted to do it, would be to overwrite all profile links on pages with links that include the profile tab parameter, so you'd go straight there.